# How to convert a mixed PHP String into the number only

Tags: php

I have a string like this:

```
$string = 'e.g. 25.32';
```

I want to pull out only the number (25.32)

The text surrounding the number could potentially be any non-number.

Comment: what if your string will contain more than one number? for example `e.g. 10.5 and 12.7` ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this has been asked before. Please use the search and the releated column on the right.

Answer (score 3):

You could use something like :

```
<?php
     $str = "e.g. 25";
     $val = (int)$str;
?>
```

But it's **not the best solution**.

---

A "stronger" and **universal** alternative is...

**Code :** (UPDATED)

```
<?php
    $str = "e.g. 25.32";

    preg_match("/([0-9]+[\.,]?)+/",$str,$matches);

    $val = $matches[0];

    echo $val;
?>
```

**Output :**

```
25.32
```

---

**As a function :** (UPDATED)

```
<?php
      function getInt($str)
      {
            preg_match("/([0-9]+[\.,]?)+/",$str,$matches);
            return $matches[0];
      }
?>
```

**Usage :**

```
<?php
      $val = getInt("e.g. 25.32");
?>
```

Comment: that does not return floats, only integers.

Answer (score 2):

If the number is simple:

```
([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)
```

You then want to match this at the end of the string:

```
$string = 'e.g. 25.32';
$number = preg_replace('~^.*?([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$~', '$1', $string);
```

This will make `$number` contain `"25.32"`, convert it to float if you need the float value:

```
$float = (float) $number;
```

This code does only work if there actually is a number. If you can't be sure it is, test first:

```
$string = 'e.g. 25.32';
$number = NULL;
$hasNumber = preg_match('~([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)$~', $string, $matches);
if ($hasNumber)
{
    list(, $number) = $matches;
}
```

If the number can be a number as in PHP:

```
([+-]?INF|[+-]?(([0-9]+|([0-9]*[\.][0-9]+)|([0-9]+[\.][0-9]*))|([0-9]+|(([0-9]*[\.][0-9]+)|([0-9]+[\.][0-9]*)))[eE][+-]?[0-9]+))
```

So take care what you actually need to match.

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions if you know the format of your string with [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Answer (score 1):

My old function that also works with negative numbers:

```
function getNumber($str){
    return floatval(preg_replace('/^[^\d-]+/','',$str));
}
```